# Sorry,the application sudo has stopped unexpectedly?

Tags: 16.04, sudo, bug-reporting

I powered on my Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot and got a system error. I selected to report it and this is what popped up. What do I do about this? And more importantly how am I even supposed to read this?

[image: Screen shot of error]

Comment: Did you try a reboot?

Comment: Yes twice. It pops up every time. I'm working to expand my partition because of other reasons now. Maybe that'll fix it. But if there's a root cause I'd like to know what it is so I can handle it.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the sudo package? I Don't really know where to go from here. Sorry. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1567012

Comment: @brndn2k hmmm so basically it got marked as a duplicate of a bug that got closed because it was resolved? That's hmmm.... Guess I found a weird one again. I think I'm cursed when it comes to linux. Every time I think it's fine some new problem comes to get me.

Comment: Have you made sure your system is up to date?

Comment: i'm not sure i'm pretty new to linux I just started using it this semester for class. How would I check that?

Comment: The software center should have an update section, and I would normally suggest `sudo apt dist-upgrade` but that may not work here...

Comment: You could also try these instructions https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

Comment: Also the bug appears to have been marked as a duplicate, not closed, so the bug is still active.

Comment: @brndn2k `sudo apt dist-upgrade` looks to have fixed the problem. Let me try restarting again

Comment: Good luck. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Tested it a bit and it works fine now. Thank you for the help. If you post it as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Happy to help. Answer is up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1567012), but upgrading your system should upgrade your sudo package and fix it.

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Will upgrade your system and hopefully fix the error.